# how to set waypoint itinerary with google maps and ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I need to display a map on the screen, where there is an itinerary of the places I need to go.

I need it to be displayed in sequence, and for the map to show me the full route of the places I need to go in sequence.

I know that markers can be created, but I would like to create points on the map in sequence starting from a starting location and an ending location, there may be multiple locations but I want the map to trace the full route between the locations in the visit sequence.

**I didn't find anything that would allow me to do this in the Google Maps API documentation, is it possible to do this?**

Comment: I believe you should start checking Directions service documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, i've done 2 waypoints that the map need to go, and then render the map with those, solving TSP problem (Travelling salesman problem)

```
loadMap(){
  // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
  let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  // create map
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
    center: this.start,
    zoom: 13
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

    var request = {
      origin:{lat: -34.6496604, lng: -58.4047352},
      destination:{lat: -34.650078, lng: -58.402425},
      waypoints: //your array of waypoints, example [{
                       location:{lat: -34.597353,lng: -58.415832},
                       stopover: true
                   },
                   {
                       location:{lat: -34.608441,lng: -58.406194},
                       stopover: true
                    }],
      optimizeWaypoints:true,
      provideRouteAlternatives: false,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Solved with Javascript API from google maps, for further information check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Hello, I would like to do the same thing using a cordova plugin, but I don't know if it has DirectionsService, I don't know if I can do it using @ionic-native/google-maps.

Comment: I 've used that package ` "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.9.1" `, have you tested it?

Comment: I saw it in the documentation and it says that DirectionsService is not available, is that really true? Because if it is, I can only implement it using JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried copy & paste the code i've added?, Typescript is a modification of JS, so that code will work, it's a piece of code of my app that is working right now.

Comment: it works, but I was wondering if you could use the direction service with the cordova plugin, but it seems that this is not possible.